# tab host disappear after redirecting back from linkedin authentication in activitygroup

Tags: android, tabs, android-activity

i am facing strange issue.i have integrated LinkedIn in my application,it contains four tabs which has its own activity group,Through fourth tab i have one button which handles the event to display post on walls
Here's my code :

```
liToken =oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

Intent findnprofitintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                      Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
startActivity(findnprofitintent);
```

like this when button click this method call and intent pass to LinkedIn authentication page.every thing works fine here,i am able to login to linkedin and posting message.but problem is when i redirect back to my application the bottom tab gets disappeared(happens after login).can any one help to solve this issue?

thanks